# How to Send Group Name From MailChimp Plugin Sign Up Form

Tags: plugin-mailchimp

I am using [the MailChimp WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp/) so that user's can sign up to a MailChimp mailing list. I want the signups to go into a specific group in my list. The plugin doesn't appear to work correctly with mailing list groups.

Can I just dive into the plugin code and add a hidden field to force the users into a certain list?

I tried digging around in there and it looks like the group is determined from an input called "interests". I have tried sending the form with a hidden field with this name having the value of the name of the group I want to use, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="interests" value="Group Name" />
```

But this does not work. Digging around on Google doesn't seem to offer much help either, as there only appears to be other confused users or not much interest in this particular aspect of the plugin.

How can I do this?

Comment: I implemented the oficial plugin yesterday in a site and the groups are working great. What's the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC I had this same problem and I just created my own plugin by creating the signup form on the mailchimp website:

Create Form > Signup Form > create embed code for small form

Then create the form elements you need and copy that embed code into your plugin .php file. My test of this created the following html:

```
<div class="mc-field-group" style="margin: 1.3em 5%;clear: both;overflow: hidden;">
    <label class="input-group-label" style="display: block;margin: .3em 0;line-height: 1em;font-weight: bold;">Interested in: </label>
    <div class="input-group" style="padding: .7em .7em .7em 0;font-size: .9em;margin: 0 0 1em 0;">
        <ul style="margin: 0;padding: 0;">
            <li style="list-style: none;overflow: hidden;padding: .2em 0;clear: left;display: block;margin: 0;"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[1][1]" id="mce-group[1]-1-0" style="margin-right: 2%;padding: .2em .3em;width: auto;float: left;z-index: 999;"><label for="mce-group[1]-1-0" style="display: block;margin: .4em 0 0 0;line-height: 1em;font-weight: bold;width: auto;float: left;text-align: left !important;">banana</label></li>
            <li style="list-style: none;overflow: hidden;padding: .2em 0;clear: left;display: block;margin: 0;"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[1][2]" id="mce-group[1]-1-1" style="margin-right: 2%;padding: .2em .3em;width: auto;float: left;z-index: 999;"><label for="mce-group[1]-1-1" style="display: block;margin: .4em 0 0 0;line-height: 1em;font-weight: bold;width: auto;float: left;text-align: left !important;">apple</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" style="float: left;top: -1.4em;padding: 0em .5em 0em .5em;overflow: hidden;width: 90%;margin: 0 5%;clear: both;">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display: none;margin: 1em 0;padding: 1em .5em .5em 0;font-weight: bold;float: left;top: -1.5em;z-index: 1;width: 80%;background: FBE3E4;color: #D12F19;"></div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display: none;margin: 1em 0;padding: 1em .5em .5em 0;font-weight: bold;float: left;top: -1.5em;z-index: 1;width: 80%;background: #E3FBE4;color: #529214;"></div>
</div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn" style="clear: both;width: auto;display: block;margin: 1em 0 1em 5%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 paid recommendations here:

There is a nice Mailchimp plugin on wpmu.com/ but it is part of their package so you have to purchase a membership to get it.

Gravity forms has a nice plugin for their developer package that allows you to link any form with a specific list. If you work on more than a few WP sites, i recommend using Gravity forms anyway.